# How can i burn an Windows 8 iso in a USB with ubuntu? Como monto una imagen ISO de Windows 8 desde ubuntu?

Tags: iso

Como puedo montar una imagen ISO de WIndows 8 en un USB para luego instalarlo junto a ubuntu??? He encontrado programas pero son para windows y con el unetbootin no me funciona bien, ayuda!

How can I mount an ISO image of Windows 8 on a USB with ubuntu ???  I have found programs for Windows (I need in ubuntu) and the unetbootin did not work well , help!

Sorry for my english :\

Comment: English, please.

Comment: @markkirby it crashes :(

Comment: What crashes ? The question has 6 answers, did you try them ?

Answer (score 0):

Try using WINusb. I had to use this this morning to put windows 10 install, into a USB And it worked out well. Hope this helps.